# First Time Using WebView - Still Need Some Help

Tags: android

I am still trying to create an Activity that mimics a technical manual.  In a previous question it was suggested that I could use WebView in my Activity and then simply create and call an actual webpage/html document (which would have my manual-like technical instructions). THis sounds like what I Want to do....

I created a simple web page called test.htm and placed it in my RAW folder and then attempted to implement the code below within my Activity. My question is this:  How Do I set up my XML file for using WebView? Do I even NEED an XML file? Does the line WebView .... take the place of SetContentView? Can someone help clarify to me exactly how to use WebView within my Activity?

public class Activity5 extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

WebView manual=new WebView(null);
manual.loadData(Utilities.getData(this, R.raw.test),"text/html", "utf-8");
```

..additional code....

but for now just trying to understand how WebView works within the context of an Activity and in relation to any XML views required.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> How Do I set up my XML file for using WebView?

Just create an ordinary layout file with a `WebView` in it. From a layout standpoint, a `WebView` is not significantly different from, say, a `ListView`.

> Do I even NEED an XML file?

If the whole activity will just be a `WebView`, you could create a `WebView` in Java code and pass it to `setContentView()`. However, please pass the `Activity` as the parameter to the `WebView` constructor, not `null`.

> Can someone help clarify to me exactly how to use WebView within my Activity?

I would recommend that you put your HTML in `assets/test.html` and use `file:///android_asset/test.html` with `loadUrl()` than the stuff you're doing now.

Comment: OK...not 100% sure why you are making some of the suggestions abaove (i.e. why use loadURL versus loadData..

Answer (score 0):

This works for a file "help/index.html" in assets, 
relative links to other assets files work as expected.

I have added Back button functionality:

```
public class WebHelp extends Activity {
    WebView wv = null ;
    TextView txtvTitle ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.help_layout);

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.help_webview) ;

        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true) ;   // enable pinch-to-zoom
        wv.setWebViewClient(wvClient) ;

        txtvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.help_title) ;

        // ''/android_asset'' is a special prefix for asset file Url's
        String url = "file:///android_asset/help/index.html" ; 
        wv.loadUrl(url) ;
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
       if (wv.canGoBack()) {
           wv.goBack() ;
       }
       else {
           super.onBackPressed() ;
       }
    }

    WebViewClient wvClient = new WebViewClient() {

       @Override
       public void onPageFinished(WebView mywv, String url) {

            // set web page title to the R.id.help_title widget

        String title = mywv.getTitle() ;
            if (title != null) {
                txtvTitle.setText( title) ;  
            }
            else txtvTitle.setText("untitled") ; 
       }      
    }
}
```

With a help_layout.xml with

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/help_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
    <WebView 
    android:id="@+id/help_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```